# Creating a custom JSON string from a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, json, email

I have a PHP array which outputs as follows:

```
Array ( [0] => email@email.com [1] => email@email.com [2] => email@email.com [3] => email@email.com [4] => email@email.com [5] => email@email.com )
```

This array houses a list of email addresses, which I need to output as a custom JSON string, which matches the following:

```
{ "email@email.com": {"id":1}, "email@email.com": {"id": 2}, "email@email.com": {"id": 3}, "email@email.com": {"id": 4}, "email@email.com": {"id": 5}, "email@email.com": {"id": 6} }
```

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction? I have tried using `json_encode`, without success.

Comment: here id means key of array only right???

Comment: You customized json string use the same email as a key, so it cannot generated from a array with `json_encode`, so you need to write your code to generate the string.

Comment: that wouldn't be valid because you are not allowed to have duplicate keys neither in JSON or PHP. can you confirm that all your emails will be different?

Comment: @Kaddath Yes, the email addresses will all be different, I just didn't want to post them on here.

Comment: *"I have tried using json_encode, without success."* -- [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) works fine and does well what it does. But it cannot do magic and it doesn't change the structure of the data you pass it to encode. JSON is just a text representation of some data, not a data type *per se*. You have to create the data structure yourself before encoding it. If you don't know how it should look like, use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) (with `TRUE` as its second argument) to decode the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just flip the array

```
$arr = Array ( 'email1@email.com', 'email2@email.com', 'email3@email.com');

$json = [];
foreach ($arr as $k =>$v) {
    $json[$v]['id'] = $k+1;  
}

echo json_encode($json); // {"email1@email.com":{"id":1},"email2@email.com":{"id":2},"email3@email.com":{"id":3}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should start by modifying your array.
As far as I've understood, the email address should become the key, the original key should be increased by one and be set as a value for an "id".

**Please notice** that since the email is being set as a key, if you'd have duplicated email address - the last one would overwrite the first occurrence.

```
$emails = array(
 0 => 'email1@email.com', //key => email
 1 => 'email2@email.com',
 2 => 'email3@email.com'
);

$new_emails = array();
foreach($emails as $key => $email){
 $new_emails[ $email ]['id'] = $key+1;
}

var_dump($new_emails);

/*
Output:
array(3) {
  ["email@email.com"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  ["email2@email.com"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
  }
  ["email3@email.com"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(3)
  }
}
*/

echo json_encode($new_emails);

/*
Output:
{"email@email.com":{"id":1},"email2@email.com":{"id":2},"email3@email.com":{"id":3}}
*/
```

Comment: Tested it and it worked, update me if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Update your example code. If you expect to receive JSON code of object that has more then one 'attribute' with same name 'email@email.com' the answer is: it's not possible!

Because in JSON:

```
{ "email@email.com": {"id":1}, "email@email.com": {"id": 2}, "email@email.com": {"id": 3}, "email@email.com": {"id": 4}, "email@email.com": {"id": 5}, "email@email.com": {"id": 6} }
```

is equal to (using Chrome's JavaScript):

```
{"email@email.com":{"id":6}}
```

Comment: (Should be mentioned as comment)

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough points to add comments to not my posts :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```
<?php
  $a = Array("email@email.com","email@email.com","email@email.com");

  $arr = array();
  $i = 0;
  foreach($a as $single){
   $arr[][$single]['id'] = $i;
   $i++;
  }
  print_r(json_encode($arr)); 
 ?>
```

Demo is here, [Demo](https://eval.in/901337)